# Dynamic data display in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to tableau .I have a data contains date and rank ranges from 1 to 5. I am showing this data as a column chart.Here bars are the ranks...

I have other table which have columns like date,solvetime,rsla.

Now my requirement is If I click on the rank bar for a particular date then in the down it should show another bar chart which displays the solve time and rsla for that particular date.

Please help

Comment: The feature that you'll want to learn about is called an "action" -- specifically, a filter action. They are pretty self-explanatory and available from the Dashboard menu. Also described in the online help and the training videos on the vendor's web site.

Comment: Seconding Alex, this is very basic dashboard functionality. Any tutorial or reference that introduces dashboards without covering actions is suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this function can be implemented using the "use as filter" option of filter actions. So, you can use the selection from worksheet 1, as a filter to the worksheet 2.

For that, I would create a dashboard that would have both the worksheets with the appropriate reports created i.e. report 1 being the date and rank ranges, report 2 being the date, solvetime, rsla.

From report 1, I would click the drop-down menu of the sheet, to select the "use as filter" button and configure the filter action, on what sheet, on which field etc, using the dialog box that opens.

Please refer this link, which provides more depth towards what you might be looking for.
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_filter.htm

Comment: FYI, clicking “use as filter” is simply a convenient shortcut that creates a filter action with some default settings. It’s a useful command, but it’s still worth taking the time to learn to create and edit actions explicitly